# Eliminate changes

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

When I select an item in the second row, the first row changes and the selected items in the first row changes and copies what I selected in the second row

I just want to ask, how to eliminate these changes?

I don't know if it's because of clearing the items in `ComboBox` and if I remove the `column.Items.Clear()` it operates well but I also need to clear the items in the `ComboBox`

```
public partial class MultipleEntry : Form
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col2 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col3 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col4 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col5 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col6 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col7 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col8 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

    public MultipleEntry()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UNA()
    {
        string strQuery = "Select TypeName from TYPE where delType='False'";
        OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery, Program.objConn);
        OleDbCommandBuilder build = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adap);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adap.Fill(dt);
        BindingSource bind = new BindingSource();
        bind.DataSource = dt;

        //Type
        col1.DataPropertyName = "TypeName";
        col1.HeaderText = "Type";
        col1.Width = 100;
        col1.DataSource = bind;
        col1.ValueMember = "TypeName";
        col1.DisplayMember = "TypeName";
        grdMultiple.Columns.Add(col1);

        //Category
        col2.DataPropertyName = "CategoryName";
        col2.HeaderText = "Category";
        col2.Width = 100;
        grdMultiple.Columns.Add(col2);

        //Product Description
        col3.DataPropertyName = "ProductDetails";
        col3.HeaderText = "Product";
        col3.Width = 150;
        grdMultiple.Columns.Add(col3);

        //Unit
        col5.DataPropertyName = "UnitName";
        col5.HeaderText = "Unit";
        col5.Width = 75;
        grdMultiple.Columns.Add(col5);

        //Supplier
        col7.HeaderText = "Supplier";
        col7.Width = 150;
        grdMultiple.Columns.Add(col7);


        //Quantity
        col4.HeaderText = "Qty";
        col4.Width = 75;
        grdMultiple.Columns.Add(col4);

        //Price
        col8.HeaderText = "Price";
        col8.Width = 75;
        grdMultiple.Columns.Add(col8);

        //Serial Number
        col6.HeaderText = "Serial No";
        col6.Width = 80;
        grdMultiple.Columns.Add(col6);
    }

    private void MultipleEntry_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //try
        //{
            Program.objConn = new OleDbConnection(Program.Connection);
            Program.objConn.Open();
            UNA();
        //}
        //catch (Exception ex)
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        //}
    }

    string value;
    private void grdMultiple_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            int index = grdMultiple.CurrentCell.RowIndex;   
            if(e.ColumnIndex==0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ColumnIndex.ToString() + e.RowIndex.ToString());
                object newValue = grdMultiple.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value;
                value = newValue.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(value);
                string one = "select c.CategoryName,t.TypeName from CATEGORY c inner join PRODUCT p on p.CategoryNo = c.CategoryNo inner join TYPE t on t.TypeNo=p.TypeNo where t.TypeName='" + value + "'";
                OleDbCommand cmdone = new OleDbCommand(one, Program.objConn);
                OleDbDataReader rdrOne = cmdone.ExecuteReader();
                col2.Items.Clear();
                while (rdrOne.Read())
                {
                    col2.Items.Add(rdrOne[0].ToString());
                }
            }
            else if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.RowIndex >=1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ColumnIndex.ToString() + e.RowIndex.ToString());
                string one = "select c.CategoryName,t.TypeName from CATEGORY c inner join PRODUCT p on p.CategoryNo = c.CategoryNo inner join TYPE t on t.TypeNo=p.TypeNo where t.TypeName='" + value + "'";
                OleDbCommand cmdone = new OleDbCommand(one, Program.objConn);
                OleDbDataReader rdrOne = cmdone.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdrOne.Read())
                {
                    col2.Items.Add(rdrOne[0].ToString());
                }
            }
            else if (e.ColumnIndex == 2 && e.RowIndex >= 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ColumnIndex.ToString() + e.RowIndex.ToString());
                col3.Items.Clear();
                object newTwo = grdMultiple.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value;
                //MessageBox.Show(newTwo.ToString());
                string two = "select p.ProductDetails,c.CategoryName from PRODUCT p inner join Category c on c.CategoryNo = p.CategoryNo where c.CategoryName='" + newTwo.ToString() + "'";
                OleDbCommand cmdtwo = new OleDbCommand(two, Program.objConn);
                OleDbDataReader rdrtwo = cmdtwo.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdrtwo.Read())
                {
                    col3.Items.Add(rdrtwo[0].ToString());
                }
            }
            else if (e.ColumnIndex == 3 && e.RowIndex >= 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ColumnIndex.ToString() + e.RowIndex.ToString());
                col5.Items.Clear();
                string three = "select u.UnitName from UNIT u";
                OleDbCommand cmdThree = new OleDbCommand(three, Program.objConn);
                OleDbDataReader rdrThree = cmdThree.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdrThree.Read())
                {
                    col5.Items.Add(rdrThree[0].ToString());
                }   
            }
            else if (e.ColumnIndex == 4 && e.RowIndex >= 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ColumnIndex.ToString() + e.RowIndex.ToString());
                col7.Items.Clear();
                string four = "select SupplierCompany from SUPPLIER";
                OleDbCommand cmdFour = new OleDbCommand(four, Program.objConn);
                OleDbDataReader rdrFour = cmdFour.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdrFour.Read())
                {
                    col7.Items.Add(rdrFour[0].ToString());
                } 
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the types of `col2`, `col3`, `col5` and `col7` variables? And what's Your intention when You write `col2.Items.Clear()`? What collection do You want to clear? Seems like You only manipulate data via those variables, so probably that's where the bug is...

Comment: @grx70 because the program flow like this the next column is dependent in the previous column for example in the type column i select network devices so the next column should only display network devices like router,switch, etc. then so on then if the user input another item i need to clear the data in the combobox e.g he/she select office supplies the item in the next column should display ballpen, notebook,etc and he/she should not see the router and switch again

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that You use `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.Items` property improperly. This property is used to access the collection of values for all cells in that column, so whenever You call `col2.Items.Clear()`, You clear the combo boxes in the whole column. To access value collection for a cell individually, You should do something like this:

```
//get the cell in selected row in 2nd column
var cell2 = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)grdMultiple.Rows[index].Cells[2];
//clear the combo box value collection only for this cell
cell2.Items.Clear()
//do the rest accessing the cell's value collection like in the previous line
```

Hope this solves Your problem.

P.S. You should go back to using `e.RowIndex == index` in the `if` statements.